# Bypass non-secure password

Tags: batch-file, password-protection

So I made a very simple, very non-secure batch program which compares the password you enter to the password in the program. Now I want to see if I can somehow bypass it (I´m personally thinking of something along the similar to SQL injection). The only restriction is you can´t read the source code. So, any suggestions?

```
@echo off
:A
echo enter password to activate the program
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass% == l33t  goto :A
start program
cls
exit
```

This is batch for

`if (password == "l33t") {start program}.`

edit: You also can´t bruteforce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see how this answer could do any harm, because if you know the batch source code, then you would probably know how to start the program anyway.

So let's try and enter:

```
EXIST blabla.txt
```

This should throw an error, but the batch continues and therefore you bypass the if clause.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, I tried it and it worked. However, why did it start the program? Shouldn´t the error have terminated the entire program? Also, how could I make the program secure against this sort of thing? Your answer is much appreciated :)

Comment: Oh I see what you did there, you can use the exist command with the if command. I still don´t know why it didn´t read the exist command as a string, or how to defend against it.

Comment: @user3207874 To prevent this, you can just quote it as a string `if NOT "%pass%" == "l33t" goto :A`.

Answer (score 2):

Here a batch bruteforcer 3 minutes to find your code. LOL

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set $ListChar=a b c d e f g h i j k l m o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

::For a code with 4 char (without special char)

echo %time%>Brutef.txt
for %%a in (%$Listchar%) do (
   for %%b in (%$Listchar%) do (
      for %%c in (%$Listchar%) do (
        for %%d in (%$Listchar%) do (
               set $CODE=%%a%%b%%c%%d
               if "!$CODE!"=="l33t" (echo !time!>>Brutef.txt
                                     echo CODE FOUND : !$Code!
                                     PAUSE
                                     start program)))))
```

You can check the needed time in `Brutef.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Type `start program` in your console. That will bypass the password "protection".

*scnr*

---

Anyway, there is no injection hole in that code.

Comment: You don´t know the program´s name is program. It just asks for a password.

Comment: I wanted to see if I could make my own password protection, how other people could bypass it, and how I could make it more secure. Pretty much just for understanding passwords better.

Comment: Also, props to martinstoeckli for finding the loophole in that code.